# Merging multiple csv files and sorting based on color

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have multiple csv files that I would like to merge into 1 csv file sorted horizontally by Color. Each csv file consists of these columns:

`Subject; Trial; Color; Response; Picture`

Let's say the subject here is Michael. All the data that will be merged is Michael's data. Currently each csv file correlates to 1 of 7 colors. Therefore, one of the smaller csv files is for testing Red, and another for testing Blue, and so on. The Trial is a random, but important number used for classification purposes. Response is an integer. Picture is 1 of 3 possible pictures (apple, banana, grape).

Ok, below is an example of what one smaller csv files would look like:

`Subject; Trial; Color; Response; Picture
 Michael; 7; Red; 3; Apple
 Michael; 9; Red; 4; Grape
 Michael; 37; Red; 8; Apple`

And here is what the second would look like:

`Subject; Trial; Color; Response; Picture
 Michael; 73; Blue; 7; Grape
 Michael; 34; Blue; 7; Banana
 Michael; 16; Blue; 1; Banana`

What I have been trying to achieve without success is one large csv file that looks something like this (but with 7 colors instead of just 2):

`Subject; Trial; Color; Response; Picture; Trial; Color; Response; Picture
 Michael; 73; Blue; 7; Grape; 7; Red; 3; Apple
 Michael; 34; Blue; 7; Banana; 9; Red; 4; Grape
 Michael; 16; Blue; 1; Banana; 37; Red; 8; Apple`

As you can see above, many of the columns repeat, but have distinct information. From left to right I would like the colors to change, with the subsequent rows containing the data for that color in 1 csv file. I am new to python and I have tried and tried but cannot figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: can you please reformat your question using different fond, bullets and etc?

Comment: I hope that's a little easier to read

Comment: Are you familiar with Python's "dictionary" data structure? I think this is the key that will make this problem solvable. In a first pass load in your existing csv's into a single dictionary that unifies all the data, and in a second pass output the dictionary through a sort.

Comment: @Zigman I'm not sure I follow how you want the combination to work. The first row of your example output has trial 73 and trial 7. Are those on the same line because they're both the first line of their respective files? It might help to share your code so far and where you got stuck.